# Why does kubernetes readiness probe fail, when manually calling the exec command returns success code?

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm, calico

I used kubeadm to deploy a bare-metal cluster with one control plane node and one worker node on the same LAN. After initializing the cluster (`kubeadm init` on the cp and `kubeadm join` on the worker node), I installed calico via helm. The calico-node and calico-kube-controllers pods do not reach ready state. However, they seem to be functioning correctly, and if I manually call the commands that the liveness and readiness probes execute, I get the expected success response. I may have a calico-specific problem, but my immediate question is what could cause this behavior with the readiness probes?

The output of `kubectl describe pod -n calico-system calico-node-xxxx`:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                    From     Message
  ----     ------     ----                   ----     -------
  Warning  Unhealthy  5s (x7 over 43s)  kubelet  Readiness probe errored: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = command error: EOF, stdout: , stderr: , exit code -1
```

The probe configuration in the calico-node-xxxx pods' yaml:

```
    readinessProbe:
      exec:
        command:
        - /bin/calico-node
        - -felix-ready
      failureThreshold: 3
      periodSeconds: 10
      successThreshold: 1
      timeoutSeconds: 5
    livenessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 3
      httpGet:
        host: localhost
        path: /liveness
        port: 9099
        scheme: HTTP
      periodSeconds: 10
      successThreshold: 1
      timeoutSeconds: 10
```

When I try `kubectl exec -n calico-system calico-node-xxxx -- /bin/calico-node -felix-ready && echo "$?"`, I can see that the exit code is 0, a success. Likewise, `curl localhost:9099/liveness` it gets a 200 code and the expected response. This is true even if I execute the commands within a second of creating the pods, so I doubt it has to do with the failureThreshold or timeoutSeconds etc. My understanding of how the `exec` command actually gets called for the readiness probes is shaky, so maybe an explanation of how it could differ from `kubectl exec` would point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, it was a bit hard to track down that it was this bug in cri-o https://github.com/cri-o/cri-o/issues/6184 because I had the outdated version of conmon from the ubuntu repo. Updating conmon fixed it.